# How to retrieve image data send from iOS Swift through Alamofire on Heroku Servlet?

Tags: java, ios, servlets, heroku

Hello I have tried to retrieve image that was send from iOS to Heroku Servlet, but i get the following error: "Response status code was unacceptable: 405"

This is my request :

```
var test = UIImage(named: "test")
    var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(test!)

    let base64String = imageData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)

    let parameters = [
        "img": base64String
    ]

    Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://myapp.com/",parameters:parameters).validate()
        .responseString { (string) in
            print(string)
    }
```

And this is my doPost method on Heroku:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.doPost(req, resp);
    String imageBase64 = req.getParameter("img");
     BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
     byte[] imgBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(imageBase64);
      bufImg = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imgBytes));
      resp.getWriter().write(bufImg.getWidth());  


}
```

Can you advice how can i fix it? Thanks in advance :)